# achartengine onclick seriesselection get wrong value after repaint

Tags: onclick, achartengine, repaint

I am new to achartenging, and I am using achartengine to draw a pie chart.

There is an onclick listener listening to the click on  the chartview, it get the series index and value correct when first initialized.

But, after **the data updated and chartview repainted**, it returns the wrong index and value. And it seems like something is cached, because I found that it returned the index and value before repainting.

I tried  `mChartView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);` but it wont work. anyone knows why?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information: code, screenshots,... Otherwise it is impossible to actually even tell it is a bug or a wrong usage.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate chartview rather than call repaint, and it works.

but, I think that's not the best way to the problem, maybe that is a bug in achartengine v1.1.0